# Abnormal Sequencing in R

Tags: r, sequence

I would like to create a vector of sequenced numbers such as:

`1,2,3,4,5, 2,3,4,5,1, 3,4,5,1,2`

Whereby after a sequence is complete (say, `rep(seq(1,5),3)`), the first number of the previous sequence now moves to the last spot in the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

`%%` to modulo?

```
(1:5) %% 5 + 1  # left shift by 1
[1] 2 3 4 5 1

(1:5 + 1) %% 5 + 1  # left shift by 2
[1] 3 4 5 1 2
```

also try

```
(1:5 - 2) %% 5 + 1  # right shift by 1
[1] 5 1 2 3 4

(1:5 - 3) %% 5 + 1  # right shift by 2
[1] 4 5 1 2 3
```

Comment: interesting idea!

Answer (score 2):

I would start off by making a matrix of one column longer than the length of the series.

```
> lseries <- 5
> nreps <- 3
> (values <- matrix(1:lseries, nrow = lseries + 1, ncol = nreps))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    1
[5,]    5    1    2
[6,]    1    2    3
```

This may throw a warning (`In matrix(1:lseries, nrow = lseries + 1, ncol = nreps) : data length [5] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [6]`) which you can ignore.  Note, the first `1:lseries` rows have the data you want.  We can get the final result using:

```
> as.vector(values[1:lseries, ])
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's method to get a matrix of each of these

```
matrix(1:5, 5, 6, byrow=TRUE)[, -6]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    3    4    5    1
[3,]    3    4    5    1    2
[4,]    4    5    1    2    3
[5,]    5    1    2    3    4
```

or turn it into a list

```
split.default(matrix(1:5, 5, 6, byrow=TRUE)[, -6], 1:5)
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$`2`
[1] 2 3 4 5 1

$`3`
[1] 3 4 5 1 2

$`4`
[1] 4 5 1 2 3

$`5`
[1] 5 1 2 3 4
```

or into a vector with `c`

```
c(matrix(1:5, 5, 6, byrow=TRUE)[, -6])
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```

---

For the sake of variety, here is a second method to return the vector:

```
# construct the larger vector
temp <- rep(1:5, 6)
# use sapply with which to pull off matching positions, then take select position to drop
temp[-sapply(1:5, function(x) which(temp == x)[x+1])]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 1 3 4 5 1 2 4 5 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 4
```